# How to shift div over div?

Tags: html, css

I`m trying to do this example(look at the picture), when i need to move the green div 10px left, and 10 px low, and the blue div, 20 px left and 20 low.
but when im trying to add this to CSS(left 10px for example), this doesn't work because there is override of the properties with the other "left".
how can i fix this?

[image: example]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        #container {
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #leftdiv {

            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: absolute;
            margin-right: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 80%;

        }

        #middiv {
            background-color: green;
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid black;
            left: 20%;
            top: 10px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 30%;


        }

        #rightdiv {

            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid black;
            left: 70%;
            top: 20px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            
            border: 1px solid white;
            text-align: center;
            
        }
        table.center {
            left:10%;
            right:10%;
            top:10%;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
        }
   </style>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="leftdiv"> 
        </div>
        <div id="middiv">
            <table class="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="images/dog.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
                    </td>
                    <td><img src="images/cat.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>call *066</p></td>
                    <td><p>call *077</p></td>

                </tr>
               
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="rightdiv">
            
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello @user17712660
Do you want the red to stay as it is, but the green and blue div to overlap and hide the overlap, i.e green left and top => 10px and for blue left and top => 20px AND hide others?
the final output should be something like a stair?

Comment: @AwatITWork, yes, the red need to stay in place, but the green need to move 10 left, and 10 lower, and the blue 20 left, and 20 lower. yes like stairs, i added a photo to demonstrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `z-index` and `overflow`, especially for green and red while you are doing nothing to red div, take a look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    #container {
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
    }

    #leftdiv {
      background-color: red;
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      margin-right: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 80%;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    #middiv {
      background-color: green;
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid black;
      left: 18%;
      top: 10%;
      bottom: -10%;
      right: 30%;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow: clip;
    }

    #rightdiv {
      background-color: blue;
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid black;
      left: 67%;
      top: 20%;
      bottom: -20%;
      right: 0px;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {

      border: 1px solid white;
      text-align: center;

    }
    table.center {
      left:10%;
      right:10%;
      top:10%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>


</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="leftdiv">
  </div>
  <div id="middiv">
    <table class="center">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="img/img1.PNG" alt="Italian Trulli">
        </td>
        <td><img src="img/img1.PNG" alt="Italian Trulli">
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><p>call *066</p></td>
        <td><p>call *077</p></td>

      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="rightdiv">

  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```